# Show json returned message in a div after each ajax response , extjs4 grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a gridpanel , a Model, an autosync Store with an ajax proxy with read and update functions and a RowEditing plugin in extjs4 .

Consider the following json:

```
{ "success": true,"Message":"Grid Data Successfully updated.", "users": {"uname":"jdoe","fname":"John","lname":"Doe","SSN":125874,"mail":"jdoe@example.org"},{"uname":"jsmith","fname":"Jack","lname":"Smith","SSN":987456,"mail":"smith@example.com"}}
```

I want to know if there is a way to render the value of "Message" to an HTML div tag (my_div for example) after receiving each response?

Comment: Do you mean a notification or "toast" message like here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/message-box/msg-box.html

Comment: A notification might not be a bad idea. But the user may update some rows before the response for the first edit arrives. I don't want to interrupt the user in this case. It seems that appending new messages to an html div tag is a good idea and makes the user acknowledge successful updates(creating a log of events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DOM Helper, see the sencha api : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.DomHelper.insertHtml('beforeBegin', Ext.getDom('test'), "Prepend this string"); 
});​
```

Above code will get the HTML element with ID `test` and it will insert the string `Prepend this string` `beforeBegin` of the content of this div.

See the fiddle to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/PddU4/Prepend this string

**EDIT 2012-02-16:**

You need to listen to your proxies `success` and `failure`: (you could also implement a listener when loading your store or on update)

```
listeners: {
    success: function( response, options ){     
       console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function( response, options ){
        console.log(response);
    },
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON YOUR COMMENT:**

First make sure you configured properly your `successProperty` and `messageProperty` in your reader. Then implement the listener where you want it to be, update, remove, add, exception etc. :

(configure the listener within your proxy object)

```
listeners   : {
    update : function(thisStore, record, operation ) {
        console.log('Update happened');
        console.log(record);
        console.log(operation);
    },
    save : function() {
        console.log('Save happened');
    },
    exception : function(dataproxy, type,  action, options,response,  arg) {
        console.log('Error happened');
        console.log(response);
                    doJSON(result.responseText);
    },
    remove : function() {
        console.log("Record removed");
    }
}
```

When you `console.log(response)`, you will see the response object. This would be your actual JSON so you need to parse it (as in `doJSON()` method):

```
 function doJSON(stringData) {
    try {
        var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(stringData);
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', 'Your server msg:<br />jsonData.date = ' + jsonData.message);
    }
    catch (err) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('ERROR', 'Could not decode ' + stringData);
    }
  }
```

Please check out this `AJAX` tutorial: http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual:Core:Ext.Ajax

Comment: But i still have no clue about how to get the value of Message field from json array. I mean I need something like a listener that should be called after each response.